# How to play a sound after a command has finished its execution?

Tags: command-line, sound

I want to be noticed after a command has finished its execution. And I was thinking that if I hear a sound is a good idea.

For example, because I have a slow internet connection, the following command take long time to execute:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So I let the terminal to run in background running the above command, but I want to hear a sound when it finished.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine your command with a command that plays sounds. For example `paplay`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade; paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/message.ogg
```

Furthermore, if you want to play a sound if the command was successfully completed and another sound in case of an error, you can use something like:

```
command && paplay $(locate dialog-information.ogg) || paplay $(locate dialog-error.ogg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && aplay /path/to/Sound/filename.wav
```

`/path/to/Sound/filename.wav` - path to your .wav file.

The sound wiil be played only if both the commands are executed successfully.

Comment: Though this will play the sound only if both commands - `update` & `upgrade` - were successful. If any of them failed, the sound will not play.